Removing rotational frequencies from a signal
I have a torque signal from an experimental adapter which measures based on strain gauges. Turns out that my signal presents very strong oscillations at the same frequency of rotation, which very like arise from 1- dead weight of my torque adapter and 2- miss alignments which introduce constrained stresses.

The obvious solution there would be to band-stop filter on the rotational frequency. The problem is that the rotational speed is not constant, it changes all the time. Therefore, the oscillations frequency changes as well.
I have also tried some moving average smoothing, but that removes a lot of useful information (this signal is to be used as feedback for an experimental controller) and, if the sliding window is not big enough, it does not remove the oscillations.
So basically, the key points to my problem are:
1- I need to get rid of these oscillations which have the same frequency of rotation.
2- On the other hand, I need to keep as much information as possible in the signal.
3- The rotational speed is not constant.
4- The signal will serve as input for a torque controller.
Which approaches could be used in this case?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Since you know the troubling frequency (frequency of rotation which I assume is forced by you) just FFT and remove the frequency of rotation - use sampling rate based on the rotation frequency so all the energy of "rotation" frequency will be contained within a single bin. Then iFFT.

You can use an [adaptive notch filter][1] to do this. The idea is to notch out the rotational frequency from the torque signal, but since the frequency is changing, the notch frequency is updated adaptively. The good news is that you can also track the rotational frequency in this way, and use that information in the rest of your analysis.
Let's say your torgue signal, $\tau(n) = A_0 \sin(n\omega_0(n))$, where $\omega_0$ is the rotational frequency. Now, in the z-domain, the transfer function is given by:
$$
\tau(n) = \frac{A_0}{2j} [e^{j\omega_0 n} - e^{-j\omega_0 n}] \\
\tau(z) = \frac{A_0}{2j} \left[\frac{1}{1 - e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1}} - \frac{1}{1 - e^{-j\omega_0}z^{-1}} \right] \\
= A_0 \left[\frac{\sin(\omega_0) z^{-1}}{(1-e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1})(1-e^{-j\omega_0}z^{-1})} \right]
$$
This signal has complex conjugate poles at the rotational frequency, $\omega_0$.
Now, we can design a notch filter, $H(z)$, that has complex conjugate zeros at the rotational frequency, $\omega_0$. Placing a zero on the unit circle will attenuate all frequencies in the neighbourhood of the zero frequency. By placing a pole at the same frequency (with different magnitude), we ensure that only the desired frequency is notched out. Therefore, the poles and zeros of the notch filter must lie on the same radial line. The bandwidth of the notch filter becomes narrower as the pole magnitude, $\rho$, approaches the unit circle. The notch filter's transfer function is,
$$
H(z) = \frac{(1 - e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1})(1 - e^{-j\omega_0}z^{-1})}{(1 - \rho e^{j\omega_0}z^{-1})(1 - \rho e^{-j\omega_0}z^{-1})} \\
=\frac{1 + z^{-2} - 2\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}}{1 + \rho^2z^{-2} - 2\rho\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}}
$$
Now, we get our desired signal $d(n)$ by filtering the torque signal with our proposed notch filter,
$$
D(z) = \tau(z) H(z) \\
D(z)(1 + \rho^2z^{-2} - 2\rho\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}) = \tau(z) (1 + z^{-2} - 2\cos(\omega_0)z^{-1}) \\
d(n) = \tau(n) + \tau(n-2) - 2 \cos(\omega_0) \tau(n-1) - \rho^2 d(n-2) + 2\rho \cos(\omega_0) d(n-1) \\
= \tau(n) + \tau(n-2) - \rho^2 d(n-2) - 2 \cos(\omega_0) (\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1))
$$
Now, $\omega_0$ is changing with time, so we want to track $2\cos(\omega_0)$, and update the filter coefficients accordingly to get our desired signal $d(n)$.
Let $x(n) = 2\cos(\omega_0(n))$. To update $x$, we use least mean squares (LMS) filtering,
$$
x(n) = x(n-1) - \mu \frac{\partial d^2(n)}{\partial x}
$$
where $\mu$ is the step size.
$$
\frac{\partial d^2(n)}{\partial x} = -2(\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1)) \left( \tau(n) + \tau(n-2) - \rho^2 d(n-2) - x (\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1))\right) \\
= -2(\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1)) d(n) \\
\therefore \boxed{x(n) = x(n-1) + 2 \mu d(n) (\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1))}
$$
And the desired signal, $d(n)$ is given by,
$$
\boxed{d(n) = \tau(n) + \tau(n-2) - \rho^2 d(n-2) - x(n-1) (\tau(n-1) - \rho d(n-1))}
$$
[1]: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1266795
